# How to replace the database from classes to connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create a web service RESTful API in the MVC project, and I followed the tutorial that explains everything perfectly.

But the problem he creates a class in the Models folder like this :

```
using System;

namespace RestClient.Models
{
     public class Employee
     {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string Title { get; set; }
         public string Content { get; set; }
     }
}
```

and I don't what my database in classes, I just what to put my connection string of the database that it's from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Because I already have my data in that database!

Is there a way to change this?

^^ for your note the tutorial that I followed is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lir75oNAeiM&t=1070s

I create this web service for my Xamarin forms application.

I hope my question is clear, and thanks in advance.

Comment: "I followed the tutorial that explains everything perfectly." - give nthat you are here asking a question, it is EXTREMELY obvious that the tutorial did not explain everything perfectly. Also you say "I don't what my database in classes, " which makes no sense. Like - it is not an english sentence that can be decipühered. I do not undersand that problem beause of this.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not native English Speaker, but I think it clear because this tutorial it perfectly and it works 100% but I would like to do same thing but in another way. @TomTom

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you already have your schema in SQL Server and you don't want to rewrite them on classes. But you need to have them on classes if you want to use Entity Framework as in the tutorial.

In the Package Manager console, run this command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext '{your_connection_string}' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Using this command will create classes automatically using your schema in the database.

[Microsoft Docs of Reverse Engineering on EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=vs)